# puppeteer - multiple class selection does not work

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, css-selectors, puppeteer

html

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary rounded-0 menu4">
     <i class="fa fa-arrow-right fa-lg"></i>
</button>
```

I'm trying to click this button. It gets timed out when I try to `await page.waitForSelector('.btn.btn-primary.rounded-0.menu4');`, same goes when I put spaces between the classes : `await page.waitForSelector('.btn .btn-primary .rounded-0 .menu4');`. I get this error when I'm trying to click it : `Error: No element found for selector: .btn.btn-primary.rounded-0.menu4`.

Comment: Can you share the page and a [mcve]? This could be anything--an iframe, a shadow root, a visibility issue. Impossible to say without the site.

Comment: @ggorlen the page is https://zefoy.com/

Comment: I'm guessing you are getting a timeout because this page requires filling a captcha.

Comment: It's important to show the whole script--Puppeteer flags, whether you're headless, etc. All of that matters. Did you print `page.content()` when running headless to make sure you're not blocked or hitting a captcha?